# ssl connnectivity issues with docker container

Tags: java, ssl, docker, activemq-classic

i'm runninng an active mq in a docker container which is connfigured with ssl support. 
when tryinng to connect my java app to the conntainer host (url=ssl://localhost:555), it doesn't seem to be working.
NOTE:
**when taking the binaries of the active mq annd runing in on the host , with non docker innvolve all works fine.**

The host OS is mac

This is the exception i'm getting:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: ssl://127.0.0.1:555?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0. Reason: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at ..Dispatcher.java:31)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:358)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:303)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
    at com.cloudally.queue.QueueManager.connect(QueueManager.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    ... 2 more
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.oneway(TcpTransport.java:176)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:286)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:168)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:338)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    ... 19 more
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.oneway(TcpTransport.java:176)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.doOnewaySend(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:304)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.oneway(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:286)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:168)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.sendWireFormat(WireFormatNegotiator.java:84)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.start(WireFormatNegotiator.java:74)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:338)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Make sure you have forwarded the host port to the Active mq docker container port (i.e. 555) in the docker run command

Comment: i did forwarded the port -> -p 555:555

Comment: Is docker running with root privileges ? Ports below 1024 needs root permission.

Comment: docker contaienr not runninng as root, but should the container or the application trying to connect nneeds the root priviliges?

Comment: Your active mq container requires root priviliges

Comment: it didnn't help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164687/discussion-between-arpit-agarwal-and-user4860092).